# Apex Junction object related list

Tags: apex, lookup, related-list, fields

Supose I have example:
[Junction object fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23626/junction-object-fields/23635#23635)

Where I replace `Employment_Website__c` with the object `Contact`. How do I write a repeat without using a class. master datail is lookup

Answer (score 1):

Use the relationship:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">


    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c">
        {!c.name}
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

If displaying all records for a given object, This works for Account(s) but when replacing with the Contact Object it does not display any records......(Not sure why, i am tired)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
  <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a"><apex:column value="   {!a.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson - yea, thanks, tired was thinking about having many accounts and contacts to display. Depends on the use but for this case you are right, only need the Account (single)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `<apex:relatedList>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm). You don't have as much control over which fields display (just whatever would show on the layout), but it's hard to beat for simplicity.

```
<apex:page standardController="Parent__c">
    <apex:relatedList list="Children__r" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It's either the search layout or the tab layout for the object that controls which fields display when using apex:related list